# How would I incorporate haptic/taptic feedback in my app with angular and nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to find a way of doing this, but so far with a bunch of googling I can't seem to find anything. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing, but I'd like to include haptics into my app if I could as a user experience thing. I can't seem to find any information on google about doing this so I figured I'd reach out to you guys.

Does anyone know how to incorporate haptics into a NativeScript mobile app? If so how would I go about doing this? I've tried TapticEngine, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using PWA: you can achieve this. With the progressive web apps (PWAs) can:

Send push messages
Use touch gestures and your phone’s accelerometer
Use your phone’s camera, microphone and haptic/vibration hardware

Comment: @RagavanRajan how would I go about doing this with nativescript? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Pls check the following official article. Eventually using nativescript you can build pwa. URL. https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-build-a-pwa-an-ios-app-and-an-android-app-from-one-codebase. So from my above comment PWA has the haptic feature which you can utilize. Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in NativeScript by either using the [Taptic Engine plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-taptic-engine) or by simply calling the native functions directly, like this:

```
let feedbackGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator.alloc().init();
feedbackGenerator.notificationOccurred(UINotificationFeedbackType.Success);
feedbackGenerator = null;
```

But I would recommend you use the plugin.

Comment: I've tried the taptic engine, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Suggestions on how to use it?

Comment: Could you share more information? Perhaps show the code in which you are trying to use the plugin? What device are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

For triggering a haptic/taptic feedback in your angular app you can use the following line of code, where the vibration will be 500ms long:

```
window.navigator.vibrate(500);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API#browser_compatibility) you will find a documentation.

Please notice that this feature only works on mobile devices on supported browsers. Safari does not support this functionality